# How many consonant and vowel combination types are there in English?

Tags: spelling, vowels, consonants

I'm an ESL learner and I'm not so good at English yet.

I want to find official documents, links, guides, etc. which contain rules about consonants and vowels *blending* together.

Which rules decide which letters can go together and which cannot?

For example:

> ***q*** must go with ***u***:
>
> ***qu***-

Are there any good references you can provide me with?

Comment: There isn't any rule about that. Which letter follows a consonant depends from the origin of the word. For example, in _qanat_, Q is followed by A, and in _qi_ Q is followed by I; _qanat_ is a word that comes from Persian, while _qi_ comes from Chinese.

Comment: I think this question asks more about analysis of the language than about an actual practical problem with the language, and as such would be a better fit at EL&U.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a resource request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phonics is a key way to learn common letter combinations when spelling words.
You can read more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonics

"Phonics is a method for teaching reading and writing the English language by developing learners' phonemic awareness—the ability to hear, identify, and manipulate phonemes—in order to teach the correspondence between these sounds and the spelling patterns (graphemes) that represent them."

For example: "ing" or "ph" usually have a certain sound, so that when spoken you can reasonably guess the correct letter combination.

Of course, some words borrowed from foreign languages will break those rules, but for common English it should be OK.